# How can I reattach to the Ziplock bag its slider that separated?

Tags: kitchen

[The following picture](http://jameystegmaier.com/2014/10/the-plastic-slider-fell-off-my-ziploc-bag-a-survivors-true-tale-of-survival-against-all-odds/) depicts my problem:

[image: http://jameystegmaier.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/zip-lock.jpg]

I photographed some more:

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are like 13-14 cents per bag... Just use a new one?

Comment: You don't even need the slider to seal the bag, simply pinch one end and slide along the seal until closed.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Ugh. And where does that wasted plastic wind up afterwards?  (The answer is in our rivers, lakes, seas, oceans, and overflowing landfills.)

Comment: Had that happen and did what you suggested. Voila it worked! It's how the deli packs the sliced goods. Not going to throw it away if I don't have to until the deli items are devoured. Thank you!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Solution to that is more about eliminating the bags rather than spending a lot of effort trying to save one that will still wind up in a landfill.  Wax paper is biodegradable, at least, and can be heat sealed...

Answer (score 3):

Pinch the two ends of the bag together and slide them on, I'm not sure if this works all the time but I used this method a few times and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

First, get your finger underneath the tab, so that you are pinching the inner tab from the outside.
Next, pull the tab from underneath as if you are opening a bag of chips.
There should be a small opening now, from there, you should be able to easily separate the bag and re-attach the slider. :)

Answer (score 1):

So you’ll need to separate the seal on the bag and have it open, then try and wedge the front half into one gap in the slider and the others half into the other gap in the slider. Like a train on its track it should now move back and forth sealing and unsealing the bag.